# My array class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

I'm trying to do this with `Dictionary`, `Array` seems more general so I'm using it as an example.

```
Class MyArray
{
    private Array array;

    public Array [p] // a property
    {
        get {return array[p]};
        set
        {
            array[p] = value;
            more_stuff();
        }
    }
}
```

This is sudo-code. I've included only a part of the class, where my problem would be. Can I use a property as above, or another structure to achieve this?

```
(new MyArray[]{4, 3, 1, 5})[2] = 4;
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: Creating my own class, that in this case uses an array, with array like [ ] functionality/interface. See the name I chose for the class and what I seem to be trying to do above. I need more tasks to occur for each assignment to the array, as shown with more_stuff().

Comment: I think you are looking for and indexer  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

So you're class should look like this:

```
class MyArray<T>
{
    private T[] array = new T[100];

    public T this[int p]
    {
        get 
        {
            return array[p];
        }
        set
        {
            array[p] = value;
            // more_stuff();
        }
    }
}
```

To be able to use a collection initializer (e.g. `new MyArray<int>{4, 3, 1, 5}`), your class has to implement `IEnumerable` and provide a `Add` method.

Comment: Super ت Intuitive too.